# Reference Xml file from csv column and then add a corresponding column to the xml files

Tags: xml, powershell

I have a situation where there is 10 000 XML files, and then a csv file that has more information for each of those xml files. I need a powershell script to reference the filename from the csv file, and add information from one of the columns next to it to XML file that is referencing.

I have no idea how to accomplish this.

Comment: We need to know so much more to help you out here man.  PowerShell has commands built in to do each phase of this question though, so there is hope!  To start, show us one node of the XML file.  How would you know which CSV file to open to find additional info, for instance?  Do you want to add the entire contents of this CSV file as XML properties?

Answer (score 1):

We can load an XML file easily in PowerShell.  Imagine an XML file called `Data.xml` that looks like this:

```
<--.\Data.xml-->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Data version="2.0">
  <Roles>
    <Role Name="ManagementServer" Value="NewManagementServer" />
    <Role Name="ADServer" Value="NewADServer" />
    <Role Name="ADServer" Value="NewADServer" />
  </Roles>
  <SQL>
    <Instance Server="NewSQLServer" Instance="MSSQLSERVER" Version="SQL Server 2012">
      <Variable Name="SQLAdmin" Value="Domain\NewSQlAdmin" />
      <Variable Name="SQLUser" Value="domain\sqluser" />
    </Instance>
  </SQL>
</AllContacts>
</Data>
```

We can load the file in PowerShell with these commands.

```
$file = (get-content .\data.xml) -as [XML]
```

We can then view the XML file as an object, or even select nodes like so:

```
#Display some particular sub-nodes
$file.Data.Roles.Role

Name             Value              
----             -----              
ManagementServer NewManagementServer
ADServer         NewADServer        
ADServer         NewADServer
```

We can add nodes too!

```
#Create a new XML element
$newRole = $xml.CreateElement("Role")

#set the values
$newRole.SetAttribute("Name","MyNewElement")
$newRole.SetAttribute("Value","MyNewValue")

#add it to the collection
$file.Data.roles.AppendChild($newRole)

#save it
$file.Save('c:\temp.data.xml')
```

I haven't touched on how to pull the info from a .csv file yet, but I can update once you provide additional information.